# Finding minimum of 4 columns in postgres with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to convert a psql query to SQLAlchemy.
The model that I have has virtual/computed fields and thus raw sql is not something that solves my problem.

```
 query = """
        SELECT MIN(LEAST(delta_cell_v1, delta_cell_v2, delta_cell_v3, delta_cell_v4)) ,    MAX(GREATEST(delta_cell_v1, delta_cell_v2, delta_cell_v3, delta_cell_v4))  FROM bus_battery_data
                    """
```

I tried the following code and similar to this by removing subquery and using `funct.min (func.least(...))`.

Model:

```
class BusBatteryData(models.Base):
    __tablename__ = "bus_battery_data_mv"

    imei = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    ...
    ...
 
    @property
    def delta_cell_v1(self):
        try:
            return self.max_cell_v1 - self.min_cell_v1
        except TypeError:
            return None

    @property
    def delta_cell_v2(self) -> float:
        try:
            return self.max_cell_v2 - self.min_cell_v2
        except TypeError:
            return None

    @property
    def delta_cell_v3(self) -> float:
        try:
            return self.max_cell_v3 - self.min_cell_v3
        except TypeError:
            return None

    @property
    def delta_cell_v4(self):
        try:
            return self.max_cell_v4 - self.min_cell_v4
        except TypeError:
            return None
```

The query that was being used when deltas were columns in db earlier.

```
subquery = select(
                        func.least(
                            BusBatteryData.delta_cell_v1,
                            BusBatteryData.delta_cell_v2,
                            BusBatteryData.delta_cell_v3,
                            BusBatteryData.delta_cell_v4,
                        ).label("min_"),
                        func.greatest(
                            BusBatteryData.delta_cell_v1,
                            BusBatteryData.delta_cell_v2,
                            BusBatteryData.delta_cell_v3,
                            BusBatteryData.delta_cell_v4,
                        ).label("max_"),
                    ).subquery()

query = select(func.min(subquery.c.min_), func.max(subquery.c.max_))
```

Error

```
  sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.asyncpg.Error) <class 'asyncpg.exceptions.DataError'>: invalid input for query argument $1: <property object at 0x0000023FDE38EC50> (expected str, got property)
[SQL: SELECT min(anon_1.min_) AS min_1, max(anon_1.max_) AS max_1
FROM (SELECT least($1, $2, $3, $4) AS min_, greatest($5, $6, $7, $8) AS max_) AS anon_1]
[parameters: (<property object at 0x0000023FDE38EC50>, <property object at 0x0000023FDE38EDE0>, <property object at 0x0000023FDE38EE30>, <property object at 0x0000023FDE38EE80>, <property object at 0x0000023FDE38EC50>, <property object at 0x0000023FDE38EDE0>, <property object at 0x0000023FDE38EE30>, <property object at 0x0000023FDE38EE80>)]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/dbapi)
```

Comment: If you have standard properties you don't need to execute a query, just retrieve the instance and then access it's properties.

Comment: @snakecharmerb Thanks for responding. But how would I perform the min and max of computed property? Or do you mean, grab the table existing fields  which the computed fields derive from and perform, min-max etc on backend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching a bit more and focusing on searching on how to use computed properties in query, I came across [Hybrid](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/hybrid.html)

After that just needed to do

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property

Base = declarative_base()

class BusBatteryData(Base):
    __tablename__ = "bus_battery_data_mv"

    imei = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    # Add other columns as needed
    # ...

    @hybrid_property
    def delta_cell_v1(self):
        try:
            return self.max_cell_v1 - self.min_cell_v1
        except TypeError:
            return None
```